# JSP file [/register-success.jsp] not found

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jsp, jpa

I'm trying to implement a simple registration form using hibernate. My data is successfully being inserted into my database, but the webpage is not being redirected to another jsp file (after registration).

```
package codegals.project.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    
    
}
```

```
package codegals.project.dao;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import codegals.project.model.User;
import codegals.project.util.HibernateUtil;

public class UserDao {
  public void saveUser(User user) {
      Transaction transaction=null;
      try(Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
          transaction = session.beginTransaction();
          session.save(user);
          transaction.commit();
      } catch(Exception e) {
          if(transaction!=null) {
              transaction.rollback();
          }
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
}
```

```
package codegals.project.util;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Environment;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

import codegals.project.model.User;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if(sessionFactory==null) {
            try {
                Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
                Properties settings = new Properties();
                settings.put(Environment.DRIVER, "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                settings.put(Environment.URL, "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/codegals?useSSL=true");
                settings.put(Environment.USER, "root");
                settings.put(Environment.PASS, "namya18#DataBase");
                settings.put(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");

                settings.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, "true");

                settings.put(Environment.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS, "thread");

                settings.put(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "update");

                configuration.setProperties(settings);
                configuration.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);

                ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
                System.out.println("Hibernate Java Config serviceRegistry created");
                sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
                return sessionFactory;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

```
package codegals.project.web;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import codegals.project.dao.UserDao;
import codegals.project.model.User;

@WebServlet("/register")
public class UserController extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;
    private UserDao userDao;
    
    public void init() {
        userDao = new UserDao();
    }
     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
                    register(request, response);
                }

                protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
                    response.sendRedirect("register.jsp");
                }

                private void register(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
                    String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
                    String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
                    String username = request.getParameter("username");
                    String password = request.getParameter("password");

                    User user = new User();
                    user.setFirstName(firstName);
                    user.setLastName(lastName);
                    user.setUsername(username);
                    user.setPassword(password);

                    userDao.saveUser(user);

                    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("register-success.jsp");
                    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
  }
}
```

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Registration page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
 crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row text-center" style="color: tomato;">
  <h2>User Registration with JSP, Servlet and Hibernate</h2>
 </div>
 <hr>
  <div class="row col-md-10 col-md-offset-3"> 
   
   <div class="card card-body">
   
    <h2>User Register Form</h2>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-3">

     <form action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/register" method="post">

      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="uname">First Name:</label> <input type="text"
        class="form-control" id="uname" placeholder="First Name"
        name="firstName" required>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="uname">Last Name:</label> <input type="text"
        class="form-control" id="uname" placeholder="last Name"
        name="lastName" required>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="uname">User Name:</label> <input type="text"
        class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="User Name"
        name="username" required>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="uname">Password:</label> <input type="password"
        class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password"
        name="password" required>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

     </form>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Registered successfully!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
 crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row col-md-10 col-md-offset-3">
   <div class="card card-body">
    <h1>User successfully registered!</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Error log:

```
Jul 26, 2021 12:04:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.48
Jul 26, 2021 12:04:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jun 10 2021 09:22:01 UTC
Jul 26, 2021 12:04:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 9.0.48.0
Jul 26, 2021 12:04:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Jul 26, 2021 12:04:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Jul 26, 2021 12:04:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Jul 26, 2021 12:04:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Users\namya\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_15.0.2.v20210201-0955\jre
Jul 26, 2021 12:04:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           15.0.2+7-27
Jul 26, 2021 12:04:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Jul 26, 2021 12:04:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\namya\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Jul 26, 2021 12:04:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.48
Jul 26, 2021 12:04:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\namya\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Jul 26, 2021 12:04:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.48
Jul 26, 2021 12:04:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\namya\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Jul 26, 2021 12:04:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Jul 26, 2021 12:04:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages
Jul 26, 2021 12:04:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.30] using APR version [1.7.0].
Jul 26, 2021 12:04:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true], UDS [true].
Jul 26, 2021 12:04:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
Jul 26, 2021 12:04:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021]
Jul 26, 2021 12:04:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jul 26, 2021 12:04:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Server initialization in [619] milliseconds
Jul 26, 2021 12:04:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Jul 26, 2021 12:04:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.48]
Jul 26, 2021 12:04:50 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jul 26, 2021 12:04:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jul 26, 2021 12:04:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [1968] milliseconds
Jul 26, 2021 12:05:03 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.7.Final}
Jul 26, 2021 12:05:03 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Hibernate Java Config serviceRegistry created
Jul 26, 2021 12:05:03 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
Jul 26, 2021 12:05:03 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
Jul 26, 2021 12:05:03 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/codegals?useSSL=true]
Jul 26, 2021 12:05:03 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=root}
Jul 26, 2021 12:05:03 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Jul 26, 2021 12:05:03 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Jul 26, 2021 12:05:04 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
Jul 26, 2021 12:05:06 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@57799d58] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: insert into users (first_name, last_name, password, user_name, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: insert into users (first_name, last_name, password, user_name, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: insert into users (first_name, last_name, password, user_name, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Folder structure:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lslxQ8C7-tkV9SFbfx7DLMsgxfoc-qQp/view?usp=sharing

I can't embed images in my answers yet, so I've sent a link
I'm a newbie to this and can't figure what went wrong. Any suggestions that might help?

Comment: There are no errors in the log. So, once the user data is inserted, what do you see on the page?

Comment: @RaviKThapliyal all I receive is a 404 Not Found error

Comment: What's your folder structure like? Your web app root and .jsp files folder.

Answer (score 1):

Your .jsp files are under the `/WEB-INF` directory, so, your `RequestDispatcher` should include it when doing the `forward`.

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/register-success.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

This also means that your `UserController.doGet()` doesn't work correctly either. If you make a GET request by directly accessing the servlet URL `http://localhost:8080/registration/register`, it should throw a 404 error too.

But, changing the `sendRedirect()` code to

```
response.sendRedirect("/WEB-INF/register.jsp");
```

will NOT help in this case because `sendRedirect()` does a client-side redirection i.e. the browser makes a fresh new request and anything under `/WEB-INF` is NOT directly accessible from *outside* the web app.

Move the `register.jsp` to `/src/main/webapp` and the `doGet()` will start working as it is.